# Print rounded corner table cell in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm trying to print a rounded corner table. In that case, the TDs must be bordered. That's my code:

```
table {
    /*border-collapse: collapse;*/
    border-spacing: 0;
}

table tr td {
        border: 1px solid #333;
        border-bottom: 0;
        border-right: 0;
        padding-left: 4px;
        padding-right: 4px;
        line-height: 28px;
    }

        table tr td:last-child {
            border-right: 1px solid #000;
        }

    table tr:last-child td {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    }

    table tr:first-child td:last-child {
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 0 0;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 0 0;
        border-radius: 0 4px 0 0;
        border-width: 1px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>adsfasdfasdfasfasd</td>
        <td>adsfasdfasdfasfasd</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gdkgkgwL/2/

The output is fine in all browsers:

[image]

When I print the page in IE is fine, but not in Chrome:

[image]

What should I do to make it work in Chrome?

Comment: Works fine with me on chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/q809k14j/

Comment: did you print the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a Chrome bug which has been around for some time:

> Steps to reproduce the problem:
>
> 1. Create an HTML Block element (e.g. Hello World)
> 2. Style the block element with at-least 1 border-radius with an adjacent side that is missing a border (e.g. Hello World)
> 3. Open this page in Google Chrome and view print preview or print
> 4. Notice that extra thick border-top

(https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=175539.)

The issue seems to occur if the borders do not share the color or width. To fix your example make the following changes:

- In `table tr td:last-child` change `border-right: 1px solid #000;` to `border-right: 1px solid #333;`
- In `table tr:last-child td` change `border-bottom: 1px solid #000;` to `border-bottom: 1px solid #333;`

This ensures that all the sides are the same which stops the bug from happening.

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
table {
  /*border-collapse: collapse;*/
  border-spacing: 0;
}
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  line-height: 28px;
}
table tr td:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #333;
}
table tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}
table tr:first-child td:last-child {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 4px 0 0;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>adsfasdfasdfasfasd</td>
    <td>adsfasdfasdfasfasd</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/3kqk327q/

Comment: Thank you very much sir!

Comment: Looks like that colspan cells are causing problem too. http://jsfiddle.net/3kqk327q/2/ Do you know some workaround?

Comment: Hmm, not off the top of my head. I'll take a look and get back to you.

Comment: The issue is because `table tr:last-child td {border-bottom: 1px solid #333;}` only adds the bottom border to the `td`s in the last `tr` of the `table`. This means that the bug is reintroduced as the cell with the rounded corner has no bottom border. To fix, change your logic so that the top border is omitted from every `td` apart from those in the first `tr`. http://jsfiddle.net/3kqk327q/3/